# Extra argument error when initializing NSXMLDocument

Tags: swift, nsxmldocument

I'm trying to create an NSXMLDocument in Swift, but I'm getting a "Extra argument 'contentsOfURL' in call when I try to create my NSXMLDocument, here's my code :

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(self.cityField.stringValue)&mode=xml")
var category = NSXMLDocumentContentKind.XMLKind.rawValue
var error: NSError? = NSError()

var document = NSXMLDocument(contentsOfURL: url, options: category, error: &error)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

**EDIT** : Actually, replacing the initialisation with this :

```
var document = NSXMLDocument(contentsOfURL: url!, options: kNilOptions, error: &error)
```

Works, it was first of all the options parameter that was problematic (and also I had to unwrap the url), **but now, I'm not getting how to select a specific option if I want to ? What was the problem here ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the type inference for `url`. (You can do this by option-clicking the variable name anywhere it's used.) You'll find it's of type `NSURL?` (aka `Optional<NSURL>`), not `NSURL`. The `NSXMLDocument` initializer `init?(contentsOfURL:options:error:)` requires a non-optional url, so your invocation of that initializer fails type-checking... and then produces a bogus error message.

(Because it failed the type check, it assumes you're trying to call a different initializer... if that were so, your problem would indeed be that you have the wrong arguments. Might be worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.)

You get an optional out of your `NSURL(string:)` invocation because that initializer is [failable](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17). If you pass a string that is not a valid URL, that initializer returns nil instead of a valid `NSURL` instance. Swift is pretty serious about making sure you're aware of and correctly handling possible nils in your code, because otherwise they can cause problems for your app.

Your solution of force-unwrapping the optional (by passing `url!` to `NSXMLDocument`) "works" in that it satisfies the compiler: you've made sure that the value being passed to `NSXMLDocument` is of non-optional `NSURL` type. But you haven't really handled the possible nil — if your url is really nil, your app will crash on that line. It's safest to [test optionals for nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) before using them — and you really ought to do that in this case because the contents of your string can change at runtime, possibly creating a bogus URL.

Besides that, you have a type mismatch on the `options` parameter, too: The raw type of the `NSXMLDocumentContentKind` enum is `UInt`, but the type expected by that parameter is `Int`. You can convert it with `Int(NSXMLDocumentContentKind.XMLKind.rawValue)`. (This one is definitely worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about — Apple's interfaces should make sure the enum and initializer types match.)

---

Finally, an unrelated tip: You're using `var` for everything, but you're (as far as you've shown) not ever changing what your variables point to. Use `let` for things that don't change, like `url`, `category`, and probably `document` (remember, you can have a constant reference to a mutable object). This lets the compiler help you make sure your code is correct, and can (theoretically at least) help it generate optimized code at build time, too.

Comment: Thank you for giving the general method to see where the bug was (and these advices) ! And yes, I'll fill a bug report. And thanks for mentioning the failable initializer, I had heard this term but never realized it was doing that while it was exactly what I was searching for some of my classes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong, there was two problems :
 - I had to unwrap the `NSURL`
 - The biggest problem was that my `NSXMLDocumentContentKind.XMLKind.rawValue` was a `UInt` while the `init` was expecting an `Int` so I replaced my code with this :

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(self.cityField.stringValue)&mode=xml")
var category = Int(NSXMLDocumentContentKind.XMLKind.rawValue)
var error:NSError?
var document = NSXMLDocument(contentsOfURL: url!, options: category, error: &error)
```

And it works fine :)